# Get UserID from RosterResource Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 5 tables: Location, Charge, Resource, Roster and SpecialRoster.

```
CREATE TABLE Location(
LocationID int identity,
StartDate datetime,
DaysInRoster int)

CREATE TABLE Charge(
ChargeID int identity,
TotalAmount money,
ChargeDate datetime,
UserID int)

CREATE TABLE [Resource](
ResourceID int identity,
ResourceName varchar(100))

CREATE TABLE Roster(
RosterDay int,
ResourceID int,
StartDate datetime,
EndDate datetime,
UserID int)

CREATE TABLE SpecialRoster(
RosterDate datetime,
ResourceID int,
UserID int)
```

I need to construct a report which shows the sum of Charge.TotalAmount on different days, by ResourceID.

Charge only has a UserID, but the rules are fairly simple:
If the date and ResourceID is in SpecialRoster, the UserID is taken from SpecialRoster
If not, the UserID for the Resource and the RosterDay for the date is taken from the Roster current at that time

Basically, I need to map ResourceID, through UserID from Roster or SpecialRoster, to Charge.

The RosterDay is the current day of the roster, and can be calculated from location, where the `RosterDay = DateDiff(day, Location.RosterStartDate, GetDate()) % Location.DaysInRoster`

that is, the modulus of the difference between the start of the entire roster at that location, with the number of days in a roster period.

I have written a Function to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetRosteredUser
(
@ResourceID int,
@Date datetime,
@LocationID int
)
RETURNS  int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @UserID int
DECLARE @RosterOffset int

Select @UserID = UserID from SpecialRoster Where ResourceID = @ResourceID and RosterDate = @Date 

If @UserID is NOT NULL 
    return @UserID
else
    Select @RosterOffset = DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, @Date) % DaysInRoster 
    from Location Where LocationID = @LocationID

    Select @UserID = UserID from Roster Where ResourceID = @ResourceID and RosterDay = @RosterOffset
    and ( @Date between StartDate and EndDate or @Date > StartDate and EndDate is NULL)
    return @UserID
END
GO
```

But the function isn't great as it is slow, and only allows the report to be run for a single day at a time:

```
Select a.ResourceID, Name, a.UserID, Sum(c.TotalAmount ) as AmountCharged
from Charge  c 
left outer join (
Select ResourceID, Name, 
dbo.GetUserByResourceDate(ResourceID, '1/FEB/2013', 1) as UserID 
from [Resource]) a
on c.UserID = a.UserID 
Where ChargeDate between '1/FEB/2013' and '2/FEB/2013'
group by a.ResourceID, Name, a.UserID
```

Is there a better way to do this? A User will want to run this to compare productivity of a resource over a period of time. eg:

```
Date         ResourceID Name    UserID   TotalAmount
01/FEB/2013  1          Sales1  22       $1024
02/FEB/2013  1          Sales1  11       $1454
03/FEB/2013  1          Sales1  14       $1900
04/FEB/2013  1          Sales1  23       $3045
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this might be of help:

```
SELECT
  re.ResourceID,
  re.ResourceName,
  ch.UserID,
  AmountCharged = SUM(ch.TotalAmount)
FROM
  Location lo
  CROSS JOIN Charge ch
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, lo.StartDate, ch.ChargeDate) % lo.DaysInRoster
  ) x (RosterDay)
  INNER JOIN
    [Resource] re
    LEFT JOIN Roster ro
    ON
      ro.RosterDay = x.RosterDay
      AND ch.ChargeDate BETWEEN ro.StartDate
      AND ro.RecourceID = re.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN SpecialRoster sr
    ON
      sr.RosterDate = ch.ChargeDate
      AND sr.RecourceID = re.ResourceID
  ON
    ch.UserID = ISNULL(sr.UserID, ro.UserID)
GROUP BY
  re.ResourceID,
  re.ResourceName,
  ch.UserID
WHERE
  lo.LocationID = @LocationID
  AND ch.ChargeDate BETWEEN ...
;
```

In the above script, it is assumed that all datetime values are in fact only dates.

Also, I was somewhat surprised not to found a connection between `Location` and any of the other tables specified. If there is one and you simply forgot to mention it, please let me know if you need any help with incorporating the necessary condition(s) into the script.

Comment: Thanks, this looks better than the solution I wrote in the mean time. I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know how I go. Thanks very much for your time.
Location table is linked to Charge, but I omitted it and about 120 other fields to simplify the question, for all intents and purposes - locationID is only ever fed in by the reporting tool. Cheers!